# Data with timestamp group to month(like Jan, Feb, March) and showing as total count for month in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

With Highcharts, is it possible to draw a column chart month wise(like Jan, Feb, March), As data I have the timestamp, but unable to group the Data to each month column.

http://jsfiddle.net/k6onhj2x`enter code here`

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    }
```

here the chart is on timestamp but i want to convert this to monthwise.

Comment: Do you have control over the data coming in? There is an example here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/ where you can use the "stack" property of each item in the series. You could set the "stack" value to the name of the month.

Comment: No i dont have control over the data, i want to group all the timestamp from jan 1,2015 to jan 31,2015 as single column and show the count for all Jan data as total count for jan.

Comment: Can't you just group data before rendering the chart? Like sum/average values for months, then display that data on the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in **`Highcharts`**, but in **`Highstock`** it is. There's the option **dataGrouping** which you can put on `plotOptions`:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        dataGrouping: {
            forced: true,
            units: [['month', [1]]]
        }
    }
}
```

This will force the chart to group the data in every **1** month.
But using **Highstock** will change most of your options, which you can change back.

Here's what it will look like after changing all the options: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6onhj2x/2/)

As I've said there are lots of options that you have to change for it to look like the same, such as **legend**, **rangeSelector**, **navigator**, **yAxis.opposite** and **scrollbar**.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for, but i cannot use highstock. i have to use only highchart.

Comment: Highstock is exactly highcharts with datetime axis (which you are using) and changed properties (which I fixed). Look at this: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highstock

Comment: i have used highstock but was not aware of data grouping, our application is already using licenced version of highcharts, so i it will difficult to go for highstock.

Comment: Well, **`Highcharts`** doesn't have that option. You should group your data yourself. Vote up or mark my post as the correct answer if you think it is,

Comment: hi, can you suggest with very less lines of code to achieve this ??

Comment: How less? Every line of code we used is necessary to achieve this.

Comment: :) by less i mean easy way to arrange the data for highchart

Comment: You can fill an array in a loop, then give that array to **`series.data`**.

Comment: I don't think it can be any less. data should be given exactly as mentioned in the API, no more, no less.